# How to know if a particular DW project is using Kimball methodology

Tags: data-warehouse

When I look at the data warehouse/BI/ETL processes in my group, how can I tell if we are using Kimball methodology or not?

If I use Slowly Changing Dimensions i.e expire the old record and create a new record, and are also using a Star Schema, does it automatically mean we are using Kimball?

Comment: Do you have columns that correspond to the concepts of start and end dates? Kimball and [Inmon](https://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/tracking-history-with-slowly-changing-dimensions/) data warehousing methodologies support slowly changing dimensions. Unless you have receipts from the Kimball team having helped you design your DW, you likely have KimballBut - it's the Kimball DW approach *but* we used these house rules. And that's ok as long as it's solving the business problem. Many people get held up on adherence to a poorly understood process over results

Comment: Yes, we have start and end dates. That makes it Kimball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm only familiar with Kimball approach and my Inmon book gathers dusk, unopened and unloved, I'm going to cite [this article](https://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/tracking-history-with-slowly-changing-dimensions/) which indicates the difference between a Kimball model for a slowly changed dimension and an Inmon would be the design.

> The common way to track changes in an Inmon or 3rd Normal Form data warehouse is to use the Natural/Business Key combined with a start and end date

The Kimball approach would be to use a surrogate key instead of the natural/business keys.

Comment: Thanks. But the surrogate key is usually derived from the business keys...in my project, it is a concatenation of business keys (hashed). So what is the difference?